# IIS site slows down even though there is lots of CPU and RAM left? speeds up if users are split

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, performance

I have a .net web application on IIS and the site was running very slow(on AWS EC2 medium server 2012). CPU usage and RAM usage are both down very low.

I started up another EC2(medium server 2008) and put half the users on the new EC2 and now the site is dramatically faster for both sets of users.

I'm at a loss to what might cause this. There is only a a couple hundred users total. What are some things I can look into to solve why this is happening so I can move back to one server?

Edit: Also, there should not be much file i/o as all file downloads and uploads are on amazon S3 and not on the server storage.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try attaching a profiler to it and seeing what is going on? You know, the "Professional analysis" thing? VS 2012 has a remote profiler that can be installed and then activated on a server to collect information.

ANYTHING ELSE Is wishfull blind attempting to find what is wrong. Profiling is about the only efficient way, and should be regularly utilized.

CHeck:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads

then down to "Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012" which also enable remote profiling.